# WP7_Barcode_Library could not be found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to deploy my windows phone app but when I try to compile the application in release mode visual studio return:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'WP7_Barcode_Library' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'BarcodeCaptureResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this only happening in release mode (i.e. does it happen when deploying to the phone in debug mode... and / or in the emulator)?

Comment: This only happens when I try to compile the solution in release mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the reference and add them again...